# Declaring variables in the class that do not yet exist

Tags: php, static, constructor

How do I get the following code not to blow up in my face?

```
<?php 

    class abc{
    }
    abc::$someDynamicVariable
?>
```

I don't really want to declare the variable before hand, and was hoping I could declare it in the `__construct` function ( javascript functions' `arguments` array anyone? )

The error I get is:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: abc::$someDynamicVariable in

Comment: You definitely should declare it explictly within the class...

Comment: It's for a sql factory that gets a config object, and I wanna autoload   it based off the name of the variable I'm passing, as I have a few dbs i need to juggle ( and I want something I can use later on in my life ), so knowing what the variable is called is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [PHPs Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__set()`and `__get()` to set/get properties dynamic which do not exist so far.

Here is an example:

```
class Foo {
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->something = "bla"; // using magic __set()

echo $foo->something; // using magic __get()
```

Comment: This doesn't work in a static context, as per https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39678

Comment: That's why this is not done in a staic context. However, adding properties to a class (not an object) might be done with `Reflection`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to give it a value right away:

```
class abc{
    public static $theVariable;

    // only give it a value when initialized 
    public function __construct() {
       $this->theVariable = "someValue"
    }
}
abc::$someDynamicVariable
```

or you can extend it with a different class

```
class abc{
    public static $theVariable;
}
```

extend

```
class cab extends abc {
   public function __construct() {
       $this->theVariable = "someValue"
   }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You are using `$this` in conjunction to a static property. That should be `self::$theVariable` or `static::$theVariable` for late static binding.